# Que estoy haciendo mal en este código de Python para hacer un grafico?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

**!Feliz año¡**, estoy aprendiendo python y generando gráficos usando matplotlib, no se que esta mal, espero alguien me pueda ayudar?

Tabla

| date | Type | Result | Code | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/10/2020 | A | 0.5 | resxcsrfa01 | 805492 |
| 2/10/2020 | A | 1 | resxcsrfa02 | 805470 |
| 2/10/2020 | B | 0.007 | resxcsrfa03 | 805470 |
| 2/10/2020 | D | 0.0124 | resxcsrfa04 | 805492 |
| 2/10/2020 | C | 0.013 | resxcsrfa05 | 805470 |
| 2/10/2020 | D | 0.0038 | resxcsrfa06 | 805470 |
| 2/10/2020 | C | 0.016 | resxcsrfa07 | 805492 |
| 2/10/2020 | B | 0.0025 | resxcsrfa08 | 805492 |
| 3/10/2020 | C | 0.017 | resxcsrfa09 | 807291 |
| 3/10/2020 | A | 0.5 | resxcsrfa10 | 807291 |
| 3/10/2020 | B | 0.012 | resxcsrfa11 | 807291 |
| 3/10/2020 | D | 0.0166 | resxcsrfa12 | 807291 |
| 4/10/2020 | D | 0.0116 | resxcsrfa13 | 809217 |
| 4/10/2020 | C | 0.014 | resxcsrfa14 | 809217 |
| 4/10/2020 | B | 0.009 | resxcsrfa15 | 809217 |

Codigo

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
    %matplotlib inline
    %config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'
    figsize = (16,8)
    def generate_lineplots(df, ax, field):
        """Generate line plots comparing field for white drivers with minority drivers"""
        df1 = df.loc[:,['date','Type', 'ID', 'Result']]
        df1 = df1.pivot(index=["date", 'ID'], columns=['Type'], values= field).reset_index()
        ax = df1.plot(ax=ax, x='date', y=field, marker='o', label=field)
        return ax
    
    def format_lineplot(ax, field):
        """Format and label to line plots chart"""
        ax.set_xlabel('{}'.format('date'))
        ax.set_ylabel('{}'.format(field))
        ax.set_title("{}".format(field))
        lim = max(ax.get_xlim()[1], ax.get_ylim()[1])
        ax.set_xlim(0, lim)
        ax.set_ylim(0, lim)
        #diag_line, = ax.plot(ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim(), ls="--", c=".3")
        ax.legend()
        return ax

def generate_comparison_lineplot(df):
    """Generate line plots"""
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=figsize)
    
    #generate_lineplots(df, axes[0,0], 'A')
    format_lineplot(axes[0,0], 'A')
    #generate_lineplots(df, axes[1,0], 'B')
    format_lineplot(axes[1,0], 'B')
    #generate_lineplots(df, axes[0,1], 'C')
    format_lineplot(axes[0,1], 'C')
    #generate_lineplots(df, axes[1,1], 'D')
    format_lineplot(axes[1,1], 'D')

    return fig
```

al correr no me sale

```
generate_comparison_lineplot(xx)
```

[image: asi]

y quisiera obtener algo así?

[image: quisiera obtener algo así?]

Comment: ¿Solo llamas `format_lineplot()`, pero nunca `generate_lineplots()`? Parece que `format_lineplot()`  solo hace formateo sin hacer un plot.

Comment: Gracias JohanC, pero aun no he podido dar con el resultado donde debo cambiar?

Comment: ¿Tal vez quitando los `#` de comentario en `#generate_lineplots(...)` ?